# Combine JSON array into single value

Tags: php, json

I am trying to concat several json key values so that I can return just a single value with all data. For example, In my code, I would like to combine address1, address2, address3 into Address. Is this possible. I have tried various methods of using the .= but nothing seems to work. Any heads up would be gratefully appreciated. Thanks

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM company_com";
$from = 0; 
$to = 30;
$query .= " LIMIT ".$from.",".$to;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $customers[] = array(
        'Address1' => $row['address1_com'],
        'Address2' => $row['address2_com'],
        'Address3' => $row['address3_com']
      );
}

echo json_encode($customers);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very well rewrite like this..

```
$customers = array(); $i=0; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $customers[$i]['Address1'] = $row['address1_com'];
    $customers[$i]['Address2'] = $row['address2_com'];
    $customers[$i]['Address3'] = $row['address3_com'];
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($customers);
```

#### Changes done :

- The `$customers` array declaration moved outside of the `while`
- A flag `$i=0;` is set outside of the `while`.
- The `$customers` array is made 2-Dimensional as you can see `$i` is passed as the key.
- Finally, `$i` is incremented..

---

**`EDIT :`**

```
<?php
$customers = array(); $i=0;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $customers[$i]['Address'] = $row['address1_com']." ".$row['address2_com']." ".$row['address3_com'];
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($customers);
```

Comment: Thank you for that. However, I think I need to return something like: Address so I can use as datafield in jquery. var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'Address', type: 'string'}
                ],
                url: 'data.php',
    cache: false
            };

Comment: You want to combine all three addresses inside a single value ?

Comment: Thanks very much Shankar. Very grateful for your time.

Comment: @user1532468, Anytime mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem.

Make sure that the column names are correct. `address1_com, address2_com, etc.`

Test the code by using `print_r($row);` on every iteration. `print_r` shows the contents of an array.

Also, what I would recommend you doing is, combining every address into an array. For example...

```
'Address' => array(
    $row['address1_com'],
    $row['address2_com'],
    $row['address3_com']
)
```

Comment: Sorry, not quite understand your answer. All fields are correct and print_r shows correct values. I just need to combine  into a single name ie; Address for inclusion in jquery as datafield. Thanks